# the place where her cousin works

Tags: meaning

a. She knows the place her cousin works.

b. She knows the place where her cousin works.

Do these mean

1. She knows where that place is located.
2. She knows where the place is located and what it looks like.
3. She knows what kind of environment her cousin works in.
   ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It is a very vague statement and could have several meanings. It may mean that she knows the physical location of the place where her cousin works. It may mean that she is familiar with the physical location and the physical layout where her cousin works. It may mean that she is aware of the social environment of where her cousin works. Normally, such ambiguities are resolved by the context in which the sentence is placed. You have not given any context.